# Stata Error: Variable Name Invalid?

Tags: stata

I'm sorry if this is basic but I can't seem to sort this error out. I'm trying to `tabout` specific questions in a survey.

My code:

```
qui: ds Q3_9-Q3_11b, has(type numeric)

foreach i in `r(varlist)'  {
   qui: tabout `i' using "H:\Electricity1.xls", c(prop ci) f(3) svy append show(none) clab("`i'")
   }
```

The error is

> Q3.10 invalid name

but why would this be an invalid name?

The variable name is `Q3_10` and the label is `Q3.10`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example with concocted data works:

```
clear 
set more off

*----- example data -----

set obs 5

gen Q3_9 = 33
gen Q3_10 = "dog"
gen P4_5 = 56
gen Q3_11b = 24
gen weight = runiform()

svyset weight

qui: ds Q3_9-Q3_11b, has(type numeric)
display "`r(varlist)'"

*----- what you want -----

foreach i in `r(varlist)' { 
    qui: tabout `i' using "H:\Electricity1.xls", ///
        c(prop ci) f(3) svy append show(none) clab("`i'")
}
```

Preferable is

```
foreach i of varlist `r(varlist)' { 
    qui: tabout `i' using "H:\Electricity1.xls", ///
        c(prop ci) f(3) svy append show(none) clab(`i')
}
```

because you make explicit that your list contains variables. Additionally, Stata checks if the variables in the list exist, so any related error is caught before entering the loop.

(The `clab()` option works with quotes, but the `help` file indicates you don't need them.)

If you still have problems, run `describe` before the loop and edit your question to include Stata's output.

Comment: In this case, the output of -ds- is _guaranteed_ to be a _varlist_; that's the point of the command! So either syntax is fine.